# MATLAB - preventing simplification of equations

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, simplification

Love this site and all the wonderful contributors on it! it has helped me out numerous times, but I can't find what I'm looking for in this instance.

**Quick question:**

How can I prevent Matlab from automatically 'simplifying' an equation in my matlab m-file?

**Example:**

Code

```
syms w l a
V3=(w/(2*l))*(l^2+a^2)
```

output in command window

```
V3 =
(w*(a^2 + l^2))/(2*l)
```

**Problem:**

The equation V3 is rearranged in its simplest form 'automatically', this makes equations difficult to relate to the referenced equations.

Any help would be much appreciated

Cheers

Comment: Both are exactly same, isn't ?

Comment: It's the same equation, but written differently. I'm asking if there's a way to prevent Matlab from rearranging the equation.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning which version of MATLAB and/or the Symbolic Toolbox you're working with. The internals of the Symbolic Toolbox were swapped out a few years ago.  I *assume* that you're working with a version that's new enough to be MuPAD based, but you never can tell...  (Sorry, I don't remember at *which* version The MathWorks switched to a MuPAD-based implementation.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve what you're trying to do would be to use **strings** and consequentially using the `sym()` function as illustrated [here](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/263902) to convert them to symbolic equations as and when needed.

In doing so, whenever you need to *relate to the referenced equations*, you can simply compare their string versions which would remain unchanged.

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion. Yes I am defining the equation as a string and converting it to a symbolic equation to use in Matlab.

the trouble I'm having is that when I go to display the equation using the latex() function it rearranges itself, often not looking like the desired formula. Is there any way to change this?

Comment: @TylerDurden: I'm not sure about that, but you should be able to place strings just as easily on your graphs.

Answer (score 2):

You can suppress automatic simplification using

```
sympref('AbbreviateOutput', false)
```